# different results for Random Forest Regression in R and Python

Tags: python, r, random-forest

I am using the same data to do Random Forest Regression in R and Python but I am getting very different R2 values. I understand that hyper parameters might be a reason behind this but I don't think it results in almost halving of R2 scores. I am using the following codes and getting the respective results.

**In Python -**

```
    X =  data.drop(['response'],axis=1)
    y = data['response'] 
   
    
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.05, random_state = 42)

    rdf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=500,oob_score=True)
    rdf.fit(X_train, y_train)

    print("Random Forest Model Score (on Train)" , ":" , rdf.score(X_train, y_train)*100 , "," ,
          "Random Forest Model Score (on Test)" ,":" , rdf.score(X_test, y_test)*100)   

    y_predicted = rdf.predict(X_train)
    y_test_predicted = rdf.predict(X_test)

    print("Training RMSE", ":", rmse(y_train, y_predicted),
          "Testing RMSE", ":", rmse(y_test, y_test_predicted))


>Random Forest Model Score (on Train) : 92.2312123 , Random Forest Model Score (on Test) : 78.1812321

>Training RMSE : 5.606443558164292e-06   Testing RMSE : 9.59221499904858e-06
```

**In R -**

```
> rows <- sample(0.95*nrow(data))
> train_random <- data[rows,]
> test_random <-  data[-rows,]

> rf_model <- randomForest(response ~ . ,
                         data = train_random,
                         keep.forest=TRUE,
                         importance=TRUE
                         )

> rf_model

Call:
 randomForest(formula = response ~ ., data = train_random, keep.forest = TRUE, importance = TRUE) 
               Type of random forest: regression
                     Number of trees: 500
No. of variables tried at each split: 6

          Mean of squared residuals: 1.437236e-06
                    % Var explained: 42.05
> pred_train <- predict(rf_model,train_random)
> pred_test <- predict(rf_model,test_random)
> R2_Score(pred_train, train_random$response)
[1] 0.9014311
> R2_Score(pred_test, test_random$response)
[1] 0.3616823
```

I understand that the test train split is not resulting in the same splits but why am I getting such distinctly different R2 values and what is the way to carry out the same Random Forest in R. I have tried using the same hyper parameters I am getting from Python but it is not helping me get the same R2 values in R. Can someone please help me?

Comment: There is a random component. Did you try running both R & Python multiple times with different random seeds?

Comment: You have a random component in a random forest. And as I can tell from your code you also have a random component in your train:test split. Try repeating the script (with data split) 100 times and then see how  R2 is distributed. (I think setting a seed will not help you here)

Comment: I agree with what you are saying but how different can it be. The R2 is coming out almost half of what I am getting in Python. I have ran both codes numerous times but the R2 in both cases stay around the same levels.

Comment: Also the parameters are different. The only thing you aligned are the 500 trees. What about tree depth, leaf size...

Comment: I have taken the parameters of the Random Forest Model in Python and used them in R but it's not helping as such. Can you help me with mapping the parameters from Python to R?

Comment: For the Random Forest model in Python, max_depth is none and all other parameters are set to default which is either 0 or None

Comment: I have the same problems when for the same data in R and Python the results of modeling are different. Trying to understand "why" I came to this discussion

Answer (score 0):

As others have commented, there is a random component to Random Forests, which you probably already knew.

But also Random forest uses bootstrapping, which can change the outcome each time it is run. I have included a link for further study. Hopefully this helps guide you toward a desired answer.

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/120446/different-results-from-several-passes-of-random-forest-on-same-dataset

Comment: I do understand what you are implying here but taking that into account doesn't possibly explain a nearly halving of R2 values in the two languages. It would be helpful if someone can share an example or demonstration of Random Forest being carried out in both R and Python and arriving at more or less similar R2 values. Note that I am saying similar and not same since I am taking into account the randomness of the test train split in both cases.